# PHP login script redirection not working after login

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, authentication

I found and fixed a little bit I am not so good with PHP but any improvements are welcome.

The problem is that sometimes in Chrome and Opera but only sometimes after login sucess the script redirect to a welcome page with javascript redirection after 5 secs. But sometimes it just get stuck and does not redirect but just show a white page without error and other times it redirect and worls fine. What can it be?

Here is the code

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
include 'inc/connection.php';
$db=mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname)or die("DB connection error...");

$username_to_sanitize = $_POST['username'];
$password_to_sanitize = $_POST['password'];
$sanitized_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username_to_sanitize);
$sanitized_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password_to_sanitize);

$query = "SELECT password, salt, privilege, username FROM members WHERE username = '$sanitize_username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. Redirected to login page.
{header('Location:login.php?message=Username not found, please try again');}

$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $sanitized_password) );

if($hash != $userData['password']) // Incorrect passw. Redirected to login page.
{header('Location:error.php?message=Wrong password, please try again');}

else if($userData['privilege']=="ADMIN"){session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$userData['username'];
header('Location:redirection.php?URL=admins/index.php');}

else if($userData['privilege']=="MODERATOR"){session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$userData['username'];
header('Location:redirection.php?URL=moderators/index.php');}

else if($userData['privilege']=="MEMBER"){session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$userData['username'];
header('Location:redirection.php?URL=members/index.php');}

else if($userData['privilegio']=="BANNED"){session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$userData['username'];
header('Location:redirection.php?URL=banned/index.php');}

else{
header('Location:error.php?message=su need privileges to acces this site');
exit();
}
?>
```

After reading and testing new scripts found on internet I still cannot fix this problem after 2 months. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe if you read the question before you are mean to people you understand and read what the error is. The redirection is working only sometimes in Chrome and Opera. Sometimes it does not work and I dont know why

Comment: Sorry, I said, "we've all been there before." Now, `First` thing is first: remove all `session_start()` except the one declared on line one.

Comment: `Second`: you should always use absolute URLS inside the `header()` function. ex: `header('Location: /redirection.php')` **not** `header('Location:redirection.php')`

Comment: `Third` use the [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement, instead of these cumbersome `if/else`s

Comment: Thanks man I will give it a try. I found the script just like that and added the privilege funtion only. Do you know some better code or sript to achieve that but with procedural mysqli because I am at this level. Changing from mysql to mysqli only for now. I am good with design and CSS but PHP login script is the most important thing thats why I would like to have the best and most secure but in short code.

Comment: `Fourth` Use `$db->connect_error` instead of `or die('...')` because, the first one will tell you the exact error, instead of you telling it what to say.

Comment: Ok, I will try to make something, let me see. It is better to use PDO instead of MySqli so I will try with PDO.

Comment: Why dont you better answer the question not for the points but to mark the question correct so in the future people comming here asking for help can read your answer and get the help they need? I am sure Google will send many here

Comment: If I use PDO to login can then I use mysqli to my webpage funtions after logged in? I ask that because my entire script site is writen in mysqli

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer a low-level question. I need my reputation :) anyway, I will try to make something for you now, since I want to help. and Yes, you can use mysqli/pdo in your site. What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Is the last `else if` clause supposed to be `$userData['privilegio']` or `$userData['privilege']`?

Comment: @ShawnPatrickRice Yeah,I think it is a mistake.

Comment: @RodrigoSantiaborg try this. I haven't tested it, but you will get the idea and work on it http://pastebin.com/bRZE2nFt

Comment: I am using 5.5 or something like this I am not sure. Its a shared server. Patrick my 2 years old son name is Patrick :) Yeah its a misstake it must be privilege

Comment: Wow PDO is really less code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of duplication in your code, which is bad because each place that you duplicate means that you need to change it when you update the code, which means that there are more places for bugs to pop up later.

To help, I placed in only one `session_start()`, and I converted the `if/elseif/elseif/elseif...` to a switch statement.

Instead of dealing with the location headers themselves, I've replaced those with the [http_redirect function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php), which basically does it for you. To boot, it encodes the URLs for you so you don't have to worry about that.

If you keep seeing a blank page, then you should check the webserver's logs (apache or nginx or php-fpm, or whatever) to see if the errors are there. Otherwise, turn on better error reporting; quite often blank pages are just errors that haven't been reported.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'inc/connection.php';
$db = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die('DB connection error...');

$sanitized_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$sanitized_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT password, salt, privilege, username FROM members WHERE username = '$sanitized_username'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    // User not found. Redirected to login page.
    http_redirect('login.php', array('message' => 'Username not found, please try again'), true);
}

$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $sanitized_password) );

if($hash != $userData['password']) {
    // Incorrect passw. Redirected to login page.
    http_redirect('error.php', array('message' => 'Wrong password, please try again'), true);
}
// Just set the username once
$_SESSION['username'] = $userData['username'];

switch ( $userData['privilege'] ) :
    case 'ADMIN':
        http_redirect('redirection.php', array('URL' => 'admins/index.php'), true);
        break;
    case 'MODERATOR' :
        http_redirect('redirection.php', array('URL' => 'moderators/index.php'), true);
        break;
    case 'MEMBER' :
        http_redirect('redirection.php', array('URL' => 'members/index.php'), true);
        break;
    case 'BANNED' :
        http_redirect('redirection.php', array('URL' => 'banned/index.php'), true);
        break;
    default:
        // The message is weird. Should it be:
        // 'You need privileges to access this site' or something like that?
        http_redirect('error.php', array('message' => 'su need privileges to acces this site'), true);
        break;
endswitch;
http_redirect('error.php', array('message' => 'su need privileges to acces this site'), true);
?>
```

Comment: Also, I kept in the redirect to the `redirection.php` page, but what does that actually do? Why can't you just redirect to `admins`, `moderators`, etc...? If the `redirection.php` script doesn't do anything special, then you should cut it out.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Yeah the text was just to show a demo code. The real text is in Swedish. The redirection.php is a fancy design page where people see a splash page with a welcome username and redirect users to the page again after 5 secs. Your code looks really nice and easy to understand for me "mysqli guy". I even learned with it.

Comment: @RodrigoSantiaborg Good, glad it helped. But if you can (meaning that there is enough development time), then try to use `PDO` instead of the `mysqli` functions. `PDO` will help close potential security bugs and prevent SQL injection if you use it properly.

Comment: But the script you made here with mysqli seems to be secure against mysql injection or is not that safe? I mean in what  mysqli can do to protect your code seems to be very secure but I am not an expert

Comment: Patrick the software Dreamweaver says there is an error in code line 6, it is the sanitized string but I do not see any error. Also the last time is not there supposed to be a ) before ?> or not in the way you coded it?

Comment: @RodrigoSantiaborg True, but it's more about coding habits. If you get in the habit of using `$db->prepare` with `PDO`, then you're much less likely to introduce an attack vector for injection. Also, you noted in the comments above that `PDO` is a lot less code. Each extra line of code that you write is another potential bug. Less code is almost always better.

Comment: Sorry. There was a copy/paste bug in there from me reformatting. I had written `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username'];);` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);`. See the extra `;` The code above is fixed.

Comment: Patrick, sorry again but I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_redirect() that means my PHP is not updated. What can I do in this case? Just header("Location ?

Comment: `$message = urlencode('this is the message');`
`header('Location: /redirect.php?message=' . $message);`

Comment: Last question and thanks a lot: If I use break can I use exit like this or what is best? switch ($Data['privilege']):
    case 'ADMIN':
        header('Location: /admin.php');
exit;
        break;
    case 'MODERATOR'

Comment: Yes, you can use exit like that. But you shouldn't need to. Just put an exit after the switch statement. The `default` case is the `else` there.